# Selenium>Xpath>How to store an attribute value in a variable

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am writing automation script using selenium `Webdriver`. In the HTML, I want to use the "NHK" value in my code. How can i store this value in a variable.

```
<a class="gc-button gc-button-plain gc-button-block gc-button-align-center " data-option-ecc="0032" data-donottrack="true" data-option="NHK" href="#">Add</a>
```

Comment: Can you please tell , if you are trying to locate the element using the attribute "data-option" having value "NHK" ?

Comment: No. I do not want to locate the element. The scenario is: when i click the option 'ADD', the option-code with it gets added to the source path of the image. So, I just want this value in a variable so that i can validate if this value (after clicking) adds up to the source path of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using **JAVA for coding**, to **retrieve the value "NHK" that is the attribute-value of "data-option"**, you can use the **[getAttribute() method](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))** like this below:

```
//Retrieves the attribute "data-option's " value
String data_option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Add']")).getAttribute("data-option");

System.out.println("The value is: "+ data_option);
```